# If Statement within While Loop

Tags: php, loops, if-statement, while-loop

I've made some code which shortens a name if it is over so many characters (shortens first name for initial, removes middles names, and if last name is overall too long shortens until fits).

I had version of this working (Which is posted after my current code) but now that I try it with some while loops it complains about an unexpected { on the first if in the loop (Line 9).

Current Code:

```
<?php
$name = "billy bobby sharkingflardo herdaderpingtonning";       

        while ((strlen($name))>17)
            {
            $nameEx = explode(" ",$name);

            if ((strlen($nameEx[0])>1)
                {
                $nameEx[0] = substr($nameEx[0], 0, -(strlen($nameEx[0])-1));
                }

            while ((count($nameEx))>2)
                {
                unset($nameEx[1]);
                }

            if ((strlen($nameEx[1]>15))
                {
                substr($nameEx[1], 0, -1);
                }
            $name = implode(" ",$nameEx);       
            }

        echo $Name
?>
```

I am still fairly new to PHP, but I don't see anything wrong with this, unless you can't place if within while loops in some circumstances, but from doing some research I have not found that to be the case.

My old code which was working is as follows:

```
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('amazondb', $conn); 
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM imported_orders");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array ($result))
{
    $nL = strlen($row['RecipientName']);
    echo "<br><b>Name:</b> ".$row['RecipientName']."<br>";
    echo "<b>Names Length:</b> ".$nL."<br>";

    if ($nL>17)
    {
        $nameEx = explode(" ",$row['RecipientName']);
        if ((count($nameEx))>2)
        {
            unset($nameEx[1]);
            $nameEx[0] = substr($nameEx[0], 0, -(strlen($nameEx[0])-1));
        }
        $name = implode(" ",$nameEx);
        echo "<b>New Name:</b> ".$name."<br>";
        echo "<b>New Length:</b> ".strlen($name)."<br>";        
    }

}

?>
```

This code is to work with my sql database, but it doesn't take into account multiple middle names and if the last name is on its own too long.

I'm sure it must be something to do with the while loop, but have no idea what.

Any help much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `if ((strlen($nameEx[0])>1)` - you open one more bracket than you close.

Comment: please leave my name alone.

Answer (score 1):

Functionality aside, your code is littered with syntax errors and unnecessary parentheses. Try this:

```
$name = "billy bobby sharkingflardo herdaderpingtonning";

while (strlen($name) > 17) { // removed extra parentheses around strlen()
    $nameEx = explode(' ', $name);

    if (strlen($nameEx[0] > 1)) { // removed extra and fixed unclosed parentheses
        $nameEx[0] = substr($nameEx[0], 0, -(strlen($nameEx[0]) - 1));
    }

    while (count($nameEx) > 2) { // removed extra and fixed unclosed parentheses
        unset($nameEx[1]);
    }

    if (strlen($nameEx[1] > 15)) { // removed extra and fixed unclosed parentheses
        substr($nameEx[1], 0, -1);
    }

    $name = implode(' ', $nameEx);
}

echo $Name; // added missing semicolon
```

Comment: Terribly sorry or the amateur syntax errors, though while trouble shooting this code I encountered issue of where it would not load anything and I think gets stuck in an endless loop, and that is now happing with the fixed code you posted.